# iptables - Allow only incoming SSH from WAN and block outcoming traffic from LAN

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to allow incoming SSH connexion from WAN to LAN ip on a router but block outcoming traffic from LAN to WAN. I let port 80 open on the router allowed for web admin access from the LAN.

The following is allowing incoming SSH connexion from WAN to LAN on a router and let port 80 open on the router allowed for web admin access from the LAN.

br0 is LAN

vlan1 is WAN

192.168.2.33 is the LAN ip with port 22 open

port 2222 is ssh port forwarding from the WAN

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A  INPUT -i br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to  192.168.2.33:22
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.33 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

From WAN

`ssp user@routerip -p 2222` works

But when I am trying to block outcoming traffic with the following

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0  -o vlan1 -j DROP
```

SSH access from the WAN fails.

What is wrong ? How do you block outcoming traffic in that case ?

Also how do I prevent forwarding from the WAN trough the router but allow incoming SSH to the LAN from the WAN? My WAN is behind another router..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rules you have posted in your question, the `FORWARD` chain will have the following rules:

```
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.33 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0  -o vlan1 -j DROP
```

You are actually allowing traffic destined to IP 192.168.2.33 port 22, and you are denying traffic the reply traffic from LAN `-i br0` interface to WAN `-o vlan1`. To solve this, you need to allow replies using a rule like:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

For the last point in your question, I did not fully understand your point.

Comment: Thank you, the first point is OK with your answer. For the last point I was asking if I needed to add something in the nat table to prevent the router to do anything but allowing SSH incoming connexion from the WAN. I dont't want my router to be able to route anything form WAN except my SSH connexion.

Comment: @Erwan: You can use a combination of nat/filter rules to control what is forwarded. In `FORWARD` table, you allow/deny the type of traffic as required. In nat table, you can also restrict NAT rule to specific port (as you have done in your case). The natural way to allow or deny traffic is in filter table (`FORWARD` chain in your case).